# CreateJS Will Not Load

Tags: javascript, easeljs, createjs

I don't know what is wrong with my code. I am very new to javascript. Sometimes createjs will work and other times it doesn't. It doesn't make sense because I am copying exact code from other people's tutorials.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src = "http://code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.12.12.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var stage;

        function init(){
            stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");

            var ball = new createjs.Shape();
            ball.graphics.beginFill("000000").drawCircle(0,0,50);
            ball.x = 50;
            ball.y = 200;

            stage.addChild(ball);
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload = "init()">
    <canvas id = "myCanvas" width = "500" height = "500">
    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: open the developer tools and check the console for any errors. In Google Chrome it's F12.

Comment: It's supposed to load a ball to the screen. I figured out the problem, it was my mistake. I didn't do stage.update() to add the ball.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you already solved your problem, I'll improve your code a little bit. You don't need to mark this as the correct answer since you solved it by yourself.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="http://code.createjs.com/createjs-2013.12.12.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var stage;

        function init(){
            stage = new createjs.Stage("myCanvas");

            var ball = new createjs.Shape();
            ball.graphics.beginFill("000000").drawCircle(0,0,50);
            ball.x = 50;
            ball.y = 200;
            ball.cache(-50, -50, 100, 100); // -50 is -radius, 100 is radius*2

            stage.addChild(ball);
            stage.update();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500">Do you even HTML5?</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

1. First, I've added a title to your document, which is required to be valid HTML5. You can change it to whatever you want.
2. Also, I cached your ball object, so now it's an image instead of a shape and the CPU will not need to redraw it every time the stage is updated. It's a big performance improvement.
3. Finally, I also added a fallback text if the HTML5 canvas isn't supported ("Do you even HTML5?"). It's between the `<canvas>` and `</canvas>` tags, and you can change it to whatever you like.

Comment: Clearing the graphics isn't necessary, since a cached object will draw its cacheCanvas in place of the graphic instructions.

Comment: @Lanny you saved me ~3 lines of code on every easeljs project I've ever made.

Answer (score 0):

I see nowhere where you actually call `update()` on the stage to make it draw. In fact, the most puzzling thing is why you say this code even does work sometimes. It should not show anything on screen at all.

---

Edit: I see you make a comment where you say you figured this out. Nevermind then.